# How to convert delphi TImageList to TImageCollection programmatically?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want to assign the existing *TImageList* Handle to *TImageCollection* so that I can use my *TImagecollection* with *TvirtualImageList*.

Here *FormSet.SmallImageListHandle* is a *TImageList* which is loading images from some other modules but I want copy these images to TvirtualImageList without touching the deeper layer in my codebase for FormSet.SmallImageListHandle.

Below is a sample code I have tried but didn't get success yet. Need to know if somehow I can assign Images to ImCol ?

```
 Images := TImageList.Create(nil); // This is Timagelist 
  ImCol := TImageCollection.Create(nil);
  imgclIte := TImageCollectionItem.Create(nil);
  try
    Images.Handle := FormSet.SmallImageListHandle;
                              //this line is existing code used as Timagelist  
                             // need to assign this to Imagecollection
    //ImCol.
    Images.ShareImages := TRUE;

    //FormIconsImageList.Images
    
    // FormIconsImageListOld.AddImages(Images); // Old Approach with TImageList
    FormIconsImageList.ImageCollection := ImCol; // Eventually I will set this
                                       //Timagecollection to TvirtualImageList for Icons replacement
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do.  There is nothing in the code to do what you say you want.  Please edit the question and clarify it.  And if you havent watched it, maybe you should watch [LearnDelphi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZsmQct1e5w)

Comment: @RohitGupta there is a way to convert TimageList to Timagecolletion through UI control. similar conversion, i want to do by code.
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Supporting_high-DPI_images_with_the_Image_Collection_and_Virtual_ImageList_components